# The phing is installed to old php directory

Tags: installation, pear, wampserver, phing

I am trying to install phing using pear. I basically used the command

```
pear channel-discover pear.phing.info
pear install --alldeps phing/phing
```

phing is installed but into my old php version folder php5.4.3.

I wanted to install it on php5.4.16 directory.

I tried removing the old php directory and tried again. But it keeps creating the directory and installing there. Is there any way I force the pear to install on php5.4.16 directory?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `pear config-show` to see where pear installs the files into.

You may use `pear config-set $variable $path` to change it. Then re-install the package.

Comment: Thankyou for the answer... Actually I already fixed it by deleting pear.ini and reinstalling pear.. But thanks really.